# Unable to connect to database with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this error stack and my first hibernate program is not running.

**Exception:**

```
  org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
            at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
            at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
            at hibernate.StudentManager.main(StudentManager.java:22)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: NL Exception was generated
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
            ... 14 more
        Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: NL Exception was generated
            at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree(AddrResolution.java:613)
            at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:403)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:206)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
```

I tried different Connection urls as it is an SQL exception/error but I always end up with this problem

**Configuration file:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe;databaseName=HibernatePractice</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">manager</property> 
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
    <mapping resource="hbm/hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I can't understand this line `<mapping resource="hbm/hibernate.hbm.xml"/>`

Comment: That line for Mapping. hbm is a package, hibernate.hbm.xml is the mapping XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking following

1. Check if DB is reachable at port `1521`
2. I suspect your URL conf is wrong

It should be something like this

```
<property name=”hibernate.connection.url”>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:databaseName</property>
```

So your URl would be

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:HibernatePractice</property>
```

or try

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/HibernatePractice</property>
```

3. Maybe the issue is related to driver jar version which you are using.

Refer [here](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/hibernate-cfg-xml-settings-for-derby-oracle-and-h2/) for more detail

Comment: thanks for the answer and i'll try those steps a bit later.